# Characterization of Graph Laplacians

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, positive-semidefinite, graph-laplacian

It is known that every graph Laplacian (of a simple undirected graph) is a positive semi-definite matrix.  However, is every positive definite matrix a graph Laplacian?

Comment: Did you mean to write positive definite the second time? The answer is obviously no in that case, because zero is always an eigenvalue of the Laplacian. Otherwise, it is also no, because a positive definite matrix is positive semidefinite.

Comment: The problem of solving a diagonally dominant SPD matrix can always be reduced to solving a Laplacian system of linear equations. This is not true of general SPD matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two more conditions on a matrix $g\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ besides positive-semidefiniteness: The off-diagonal entries have to be nonpositive, and all the rows and columns have to sum to $0$. (In particular, $0$ is an eigenvalue of $g$.) If those two conditions hold, then $g$ is the Laplacian of the graph $\Gamma$ with vertex set $V(\Gamma) = \{1, \dots, n\}$, edges connecting those distinct $i, j\in V(\Gamma)$ with $g_{ij}\not = 0$, and weights $w_{ij} = -g_{ij}$.

That's assuming you're referring to the Laplacian of a weighted graph. Otherwise, there are obvious integrality conditions to enforce.

Answer (score 1):

No. The Laplacian of a simple undirected graph always has an eigenvalue equal to zero.

Observe that the sum of every row of the Laplacian is equal to zero. Thus, the vector of ones is an eigenvector with eigenvalue zero.

Comment: This may seem silly but is there a (sub)-Riemannian structure on the set of all Laplacian matrices?

Comment: @ProbablyAHuman Not sure.